# Adding Crystal runtime as Installshield prerequisite

Tags: crystal-reports, installshield-2018

i am using install shield 2018 , I want to add Crystal runtime 13.0.33.4485 which is a 32 bit as prerequisite. What is the registry node that I should check to see if this version of runtime is already installed or not?